# Sharepoint and encryption

Tags: sharepoint, encryption, document-library

I'm currently setting up WSS 3.0 at my work, and I'm in the finance section of it.

My question is, is there a possibility to encrypt and decrypt lists?
And I mean entire lists, because the document libraries will have different types of files in it, from Word to Invoices in InfoPath.

I know there is a solution in CodePlex called [CryptoCollaboration](http://cryptocollaboration.codeplex.com/), but whenever I deploy the solution in SharePoint I get a server error.

Any alternatives? Or maybe you could fix the codeplex solution, that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the CryptoCollaboration issue, modifiy the web.config file. Change WSS_Custom security policy to Full.
That should work.